# AWS Cloudwatch: Is there a way to record DynamoDB PutItem operations for specific table Attributes/Column names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

```json
{
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": true,
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/DynamoDB", "SuccessfulRequestLatency", "TableName", "table1_name", "Operation", "PutItem" ]
    ],
    "region": "us-east-2",
    "title": "table1 PutItem graph",
    "period": 300,
    "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
}
```

Can I put anything in this list to signify that I want to only record, say, PutItems in the "Fruits" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shared here is a snippet of a CloudWatch dashboard. A CloudWatch dashboard can only use metrics that are already available, so we have to look at the granularity that is offered by the DynamoDB metrics, which is not more granular than the table. So I'm afraid what you're looking for is not possible.

Comment: Gotcha, I had that feeling. Working to achieve this with dynamo stream and lambdas now.